# Multiplicaton of big integers (factorial)

Tags: c++, algorithm, multiplication

I accidentally saw on Internet that functional programming language *SML* allows to do arbitrary precision integer arithmetic. I had written big integer arithmetic on *C++* before and I decided(for curiosity) to compare my implementation with *SML*'s by computing factorial of big numbers. I found out that *SML* program works about 15 times faster than mine. My implementation uses elementary school multiplication algorithm. But as I know the fast algorithms (such as FFT or Karatsuba's algorithm) worked better than elementary school  multiplication when multipliers aren't much different. In this case they are, because `(n-1)!` is much greater than `n`. My question is what are the other possible reasons that the *SML* program works so faster.

Answer (score 2):

Three possible reasons:

- It uses multiple CPU cores (easy to test)
- It uses [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instructions
- It uses GPU (rare, but not unheard of)

Comment: The OP wanted probably some algorithmical reason.

Comment: Peter that's the case. I don't think that the reason is algorithmic.